# Conditional interface of react component, creating a wrapper component for MUI box

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, interface

This is what I have so far, but it seems that box props changes, for example when you set component="img" you now have src prop to pass, but when set <box component="span" you don't have that same src you had... And also many other things like motion, icons etc... How can I fully extend box props into my own props and make them same ?

```
  import { forwardRef } from 'react';
    import { Box, BoxProps } from '@mui/material';
    import { IconifyIcon } from '@iconify/react';
    
    export type { BoxProps };
    
    interface INBoxProps extends BoxProps {
      icon?: IconifyIcon | string;
    }
    
    /**
     * NBox Component.
     * This is a ref-forwarding wrapper around MUI's Box component.
     * Allows getting a ref to the underlying Box component, which can be useful for direct DOM
     * access or for integration with certain libraries.
     *
     * @function
     * @param {BoxProps} props - Props passed down to the MUI Box component.
     * @param {React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>} ref - A ref passed to the underlying Box component.
     * @returns {React.ReactElement}
     *
     * @example
     * import NBox from './NBox';
     *
     * function MyComponent() {
     *   return (
     *     <NBox display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
     *       Centered content
     *     </NBox>
     *   );
     * }
     */
    const NBox = forwardRef<any, INBoxProps>((props, ref) => {
      return <Box ref={ref} {...props} />;
    });
    
    export default NBox;
```